# Code php is not working

Tags: php

data_show_project.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
include("connect_project.php");
$where = "";
$sql = "SELECT project_tbl.p_id AS p_id,p_name, COUNT(tc_id) AS tc_id FROM testcase_tbl 
INNER JOIN project_tbl ON project_tbl.p_id = testcase_tbl.p_id GROUP BY project_tbl.p_id $where";
$result = runSQL($sql);
$numrow = countRec('p_id','project_tbl',$where);
if($numrow>0){
    $json = "";
    $json .= "{";
    $json .= "\"aaData\":[";
    $rc = false;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($rc) $json .= ",";
        $json .= "[";
        //$json .= "\"".$row['p_name']."\"";
        $json .= "\""."<a href=javascript:openWindow('?id=".$row['p_id']."')>".$row['p_name']."</a>"."\"";
        $json .= ",\"".$row['p_detail']."\"";
        $json .= ",\"".number_format($row['tc_id'])."\"]";

        $rc = true;
    }
        $json .= "]";
        $json .= "}";
        echo $json;
}
?>
```

when run file `{"aaData":[["aaaah","2"]]}`

and data_show_req.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
include("connect_project.php");
    //รับ pk ที่มาจากหน้า display
$id = $_GET['id'];    
$where = "INNER JOIN requirement_tbl ON requirement_tbl.req_id = testcase_tbl.req_id AND requirement_tbl.p_id = testcase_tbl.p_id WHERE testcase_tbl.p_id = $id";
$sql = "SELECT requirement_tbl.req_id AS req_id,req_name,COUNT(tc_id) AS tc_id FROM testcase_tbl $where";
$result = runSQL($sql);
$numrow = countRec('requirement_tbl.req_id','testcase_tbl',$where);        
if($numrow>0){
    $json = "";
    $json .= "{";
    $json .= "\"aaData\":[";
    $rc = false;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($rc) $json .= ",";
        $json .= "[";
        $json .= "\"".$row['req_name']."</a>"."\"";
        $json .= ",\"".$row['req_detail']."\"";
        $json .= ",\"".number_format($row['tc_id'])."\"]";

        $rc = true;
    }
        $json .= "]";
        $json .= "}";
        echo $json;
}
?>
```

i want to run file `{"aaData":[["bbbbb","2"],["ccccc","0"]]}`
but is not working

[[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will advice for you use an array.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
        "aaData" => array(
                array('bbbbb',2), array("cccccc",0)
              )
);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Result: [eval.in](https://eval.in/595708)

With your case; it should be like this,

```
<?php
$arr = array();
if($numrow>0){
    $arr['aaData'] = array();
    $i =0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $arr['aaData'][0][$i] =   array(
                        $row['p_name'],
                        number_format($row['tc_id'])            
                    );          
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

And I think your 'countRec(...)' function return wrong result.
You can try 'mysql_num_rows($result)'

And better to stop to use mysql connection. Please check [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) .

I hope this help.